# Selecting and using variable in MySQL query

Tags: mysql, variables, select

I have a query in MySQL, but instead '9999999' I would like to use variable like this:

```
select @upc := upc from lc_products where upc <> ''
```

Main query:

```
INSERT IGNORE INTO `lc_products_to_vehicles` 
( product_id, vehicle_id)
SELECT lc_products.id, lc_artid_to_vehicles.TTC_TYP_ID
FROM lc_artid_to_vehicles
INNER JOIN lc_products on lc_products.upc = lc_artid_to_vehicles.TTC_ART_ID
WHERE lc_products.upc = 9999999
```

How can use it in a single query? 
Is that possible? Should new data be correctly inserted by @upc variable?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming there is only one `upd <> ''`

```
 WHERE lc_products.upc = (select upc from lc_products where upc <> '')
```

other wise

```
 WHERE lc_products.upc IN (select upc from lc_products where upc <> '')
```

EDIT:  after reading more carefully your code, you only need this

```
 WHERE lc_products.upc <> ''
```

Comment: OK, this is working. But it's extremely slow, becuase lc_art_id_vehicles has 100mil rows. Is it possible to optimize this query?

Comment: do you have index for `upc` ?? also I just realize you dont need a subquery.

Comment: I've added index to upc. Thanks. EDIT: just read edited answer